# Create DataGridView from DataSet with Hyperlinks in Visual Basic

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, hyperlink, vb.net-2010

I want to create a program that would list items with an associated hyperlink attached to the item number.  The list is coming from an XML created in another program, which looks something like this:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <iNum>12</inum>
    <iTitle>Title 12</iTitle>
    <iURL>http://link.to/title12</iURL>
  </item>

  <item>
    <iNum>15</inum>
    <iTitle>Title 15</iTitle>
    <iURL>http://link.to/title15</iURL>
  </item>
</root>
```

With this list, I wrote the visual basic code to import the XML file into a DataSet, then put the DataSet into the DataGridView in my program.  This is how the Visual Basic code looks like.

```
''' <summary>
''' Puts XML results into DataGrid.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub XML_to_DataGrid()
    Try
        ds.ReadXml(xFileLoc)

        ds.Tables(0).Columns(0).ColumnName = "Item Number"
        ds.Tables(0).Columns(1).ColumnName = "Item Title"
        ds.Tables(0).Columns(2).ColumnName = "Item URL"

        DataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I'm not sure how I can link the items in Column 1 of the DataSet (Item Number) to the hyperlinks in Column 3 (Item URL).  Any help or advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My apology, I'm not understood that it was for Window form... Long time that I do only Web Apps. I found this one in a older programme, and adapted it for VB.NET:

So don't bind the DataSet to the DataGridView, but fill it in by a loop like this:

```
        Dim MyDS As New DataSet
        MyDS.ReadXml("MyXMLfile.xml")

        ' Define the column
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col1", "N°")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col2", "Title")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col3", "HL")
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False

        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        Dim cell1 As DataGridViewLinkCell
        Dim cell2 As DataGridViewTextBoxCell
        Dim cell3 As DataGridViewTextBoxCell

        ' Loop arround the DataSel rows
        For i = 0 To MyDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

            row = New DataGridViewRow

            cell1 = New DataGridViewLinkCell
            cell1.Value = MyDS.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0)
            row.Cells.Add(cell1)

            cell2 = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
            cell2.Value = MyDS.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)
            row.Cells.Add(cell2)

            cell3 = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
            cell3.Value = MyDS.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2)
            row.Cells.Add(cell3)

            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
```

And add a function for the click event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Process.Start(DataGridView1.Item(2, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString)
End Sub
```

This should work.
Hope this is better for you.
Regards

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the ASP page.  Aren't ASP pages meant for websites, and if not, where can I find it in my program?